# Is there a dedicated word to describe a long-term oriented person?

Tags: single-word-requests

Who, in all his or her dealings, values the long-term value over the short term. The best I have come up with is "long-term oriented". Is there a dedicated adjective to describe this?

Comment: not shortsighted, in it for the long haul

Comment: In fairness, "long-term oriented" is still better option than those. I'm looking for a single word.

Comment: "Someone who takes the long view."

Comment: If you tolerate a phrase, rather that single-world, you could say he **plays the long game** as per  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/long_game

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using the adjective [**visionary**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/visionary) which means:

> Thinking about or planning the future with imagination or wisdom: '*a
>   visionary leader*'.

[**Far-sighted**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/far-sighted) could be a good candidate, too.

> Showing a prudent awareness of future possibilities: '*far-sighted ideas
>   on education*'.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 3):

***Prudent*** means "careful in providing for the future" ([here)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prudent) and "acting with or showing care and thought for the future" ([here](https://www.google.com/#q=define+prudent)).

Answer (score 1):

For one who consistently *values* long-term value, 'idealistic', the adjective from 'idealism', might be the usual. Rather than an adjective, however, the noun 'idealist' might be better to name one "who, in all his or her dealings, *values* the long-term value over the short term":

> **idealist** *n.*
>   1. a person who cherishes or pursues high or noble principles, purposes, or goals.
>   2. a visionary or impractical person.
>   3. a person who represents things as they might or should be rather than as they are.

[idealist. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved January 19 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idealist .]

'Idealist' (or 'idealistic') has the disadvantage that, in contemporary use, it is often used depreciatively:

> 3. A person who creates, aspires to, or pursues ideals. Also *depreciatively*: one who entertains visionary or unpractical notions.

["idealist, n. and adj.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90961 (accessed January 19, 2016).

---

If 'idealist' (or 'idealistic') is not what you had in mind, perhaps 'forward-looking' would be more suitable:

> **forward-looking** *adj.*
>   Concerned with or making provision for the future

Answer (score 1):

You may describe such a person as ***sagacious***:

> :  of keen and farsighted penetration and judgment
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sagacious)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Future oriented**

Future orientation refers to [*a time perspective that is focused on the future, especially on how to achieve your future goals.* (Psychology Dictionary)](https://psychologydictionary.org/future-orientation/).

There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_orientation) that has a lengthy description, including this definition: *Future orientation is broadly defined as the extent to which an individual thinks about the future, anticipates future consequences, and plans ahead before acting.*